# LEFT JOIN Linq with a WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to do this SQL LEFT JOIN in Linq:

```
SELECT 
    romm.rommid,
    wetx.target_data_entity_type_id AS busprocid 
FROM 
    romm 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Work_Effort_Type_Xref wetx ON romm.busprocid = wetx.source_data_entity_type_id 
                               AND wetx.source_data_entity_name = ‘BusProc’ 
WHERE 
    romm.acttypeid = 1
```

And I have this Linq:

```
 var query = from romm in RoMM
             join wetx in WorkEfforTypeXRef on romm.BusProcId equals wetx.SourceDataEntityTypeId into Group
             from roup in Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where romm.ActTypeId == 1 && roup.SourceDataEntityTypeName == "BusProc"
             select new
                    {
                        romm.RoMmid,
                        roup.SourceDataEntityTypeName
                    };
```

When I execute this, I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of the object

on the `roup` side.

What can I try next? I cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: Can you post both classes too, pls?

Comment: You don't want to move that one check into the where clause as it will change the meaning of the query from including the `romm` rows that match up with a `wetx` with a name that is not `BusProc` (returning null for the `wetx`) vs filter those out.

Answer (score 3):

One way that would be closer to the SQL join clause would be to include that second condition in your Linq join clause:

```
join wetx in WorkEfforTypeXRef 
      on new {a = romm.BusProcId,              b = "BusProc"}
  equals new {a = wetx.SourceDataEntityTypeId, b = wetx.SourceDataEntityTypeName}
  into Group
```

which prevents the NRE in the `Where` since you don't neet to reference `wetx` in the `Where` at this point. To prevent it in select just use `?.`:

```
select new
{
    romm.RoMmid,
    roup?.SourceDataEntityTypeName
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the "roup" object is null try changing that to:

```
var query = from romm in RoMM
             join wetx in WorkEfforTypeXRef on romm.BusProcId equals wetx.SourceDataEntityTypeId into Group
             from roup in Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where romm.ActTypeId == 1 && roup.SourceDataEntityTypeName == "BusProc"
             select new
                    {
                        romm.RoMmid,
                        SourceDataEntityTypeName = roup?.SourceDataEntityTypeName
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Navigation Properties configured correctly then this should work.

```
var query = RoMM
            .Include(_ => _.WorkEfforTypeXRef)
            .Where(_ => _.ActTypeId == 1 &&
                        _.SourceDataEntityTypeName == "BusProc")
            .Select(x => new 
                   {
                     x.RoMmid,
                     SourceDataEntityTypeName = x.WorkEfforTypeXRef.SourceDataEntityTypeName
                   });
```